how to land some pixel before my link text
I use this code for creating a link inside my text:
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=\hyperlink{1_1}{\TaI},halign=justify]
  
      \AaI  \\
      \vspace{1ex}
      \noindent
\MaI

   \end{tcolorbox} 

AaI, MaI are text variable. This is the code:
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting
 \usepackage{tcolorbox}
\title{butta} \author{xxxxxx. yyyyyyy} \date{April 2024} %-------------riga a-----I box--------------
    \newcommand{\AaI}{ bla bla bla }
    \newcommand{\TaI}{ TITLE }
    \newcommand{\MaI}{ some text}
    \newcommand{\ARTaI}{ ARTICLE A_1 }
     \begin{document}
       \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=\hyperlink{1_1}{\TaI},halign=justify]
  
      \AaI  \\
      \vspace{1ex}
      \noindent \MaI

   \end{tcolorbox} 

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}

when I valorize variable, I compile it and obtain a .PDF. If I click the title of the box I will land to the title of article, but the target is some pixel above and I can read just few letter of the title, because it is all upon.
How can I land on the first letter of title? or some way to pull the line up for some mm?
thank you
Renato

Please use a code block for your code and not a quote. This messes up all the line breaks and we don't know what is commented out and what code you actually use.

Two things to comment: First: the hyperref package is missing, second: What viewers have you tried? Do all behave the same? Unfortunately I could not reproduce the point you are asking for.

hyper ref package is missing because this is just a minimal example, I've not included all the preamble.
I use Acrobat reader on pc or preview on Mac os. Do you think could it be a reader prob?

Sidenote: A minimal example should still contain all packages that are relevant for compilation of this small code example.
